# How to disable third tab if the first one is selected already?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout setup with viewPager.
The TabLayout is actually three dots (like on some intro pages).
My aim is to disable clickable on the third dot, when I am on the first dot.
However, when I am on the second dot it should be possible to move to the third.

I tried many possibilities to solve it.
Now I have possibility to move from the first to the third dot at first. But after the first move, there is disabled move to the third dot from the first and second one dot.

Do you have any ideas how to fix the code?
Thank you.

```
dotsView.setupWithViewPager(buildTypeViewPager);

    buildTypeViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    if (getmLastPage() == 1 || getmLastPage() == 2) {
                        ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                        state.moveToPage(position);
                        refreshViewState(false);
                        setmLastPage(position);
                    }
                    else ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);

                    break;

                case 1:
                    if (getmLastPage() == 1 || getmLastPage() == 2) {
                        ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                        state.moveToPage(position);
                        refreshViewState(false);
                        setmLastPage(position);
                    }
                    else ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (getmLastPage() == 1 || getmLastPage() == 2) {
                        ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);
                        state.moveToPage(position);
                        refreshViewState(false);
                        setmLastPage(position);
                    } else ((LinearLayout) dotsView.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(2).setEnabled(true);
                    break;
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a TabLayout? Just use view pager with dots as indicators

Comment: I work on code, somebody already is working on also. I can not change his solutions.

Comment: User removed from stack

Comment: Why this user has been removed? @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @Ankita Maybe somewhere violated Rules

Comment: Ok.. And this is also compulsory to maintain the decorum.